# Apache poi como faço para adicionar arquivo na planilha excel

Tags: apache, arquivo, planilha

Gostaria de saber como faço pelo apache poi para adicionar um arquivo na planilha criada por ele. O tipo de arquivo é um .WAV de 150 KB. Já li a documentação mas gostaria de ver um exemplo simples para entender melhor.

Obrigado.